# Change CS:IP in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-segmentation

How can you forcibly change `CS` and `IP` both in assembly language ?

`ORG` directive can be used to change the number of the `IP`, but how do you change the `CS`?

Basically I wan to implement multi-threading using assembly.

Many forums, including a question in stack overflow has said its impossible, but then how does C have multi-threading options even when it is made from assembly code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714905/threads-in-x86-assembler-using-the-gnu-assember-as

Comment: ORG doesn't change IP, it changes the number the assembler uses when it needs IP. "Changing" CS in an equivalent way would do absolutely nothing because the assembler doesn't use that value anyway.

Comment: @harold Depends on the memory model...

Comment: ya exactly, thanks but how do you change the number of CS ?

Comment: @Macmade I saw that question itself before posting this but it was quite vast and didn't solve my doubt, that's why i re-posted a smaller question. :)

Comment: Changing IP cannot be done directly, but it changes when you 'jump'. About threads, either you use the OS with a syscall, or you write your own scheduler.

Comment: @harold - Why i need that is, if i am able to change the number of cs, then probably i maybe able to find out a way to do multi-threading in assembly.

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion so that's the *runtime* CS then, right? See far jumps, far calls and far returns.

Comment: Thanks @Macmade but could you guide me to any resource. Basically I am working on making an OS, so i want it to have multi-threading capabilities and am not interested in doing it in C. If possible, please suggest me a method or a link. Would be of great help.

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion See this: http://wiki.osdev.org/Processes_and_Threads

Answer (score 7):

To change `cs:ip` just make a long jump with `jmp` (eg. `jmp segment:offset`) or a long `call` (eg. `call segment:offset`) depending on your needs. There are several different addressing modes available for `jmp` [link](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/jmp.html) and `call` [link](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/call.html). Implementing multithreading is a totally different matter from simply changing `cs:ip`.

Comment: Could you help me with implementation of multi-threading. In C it is possible but in Assembly, people say it isn't. How is that is when C is made using Assembly?

Comment: As assembly is a more or less direct representation of processor's instruction set, any program possible in any other programming language can be written in assembly too (at least in theory), and it's also possible to disassemble any given program. As answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714905/threads-in-x86-assembler-using-the-gnu-assember-as suggest, you need to either use kernel's scheduler or write your own scheduler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980999/what-does-multicore-assembly-language-look-like has useful info. You need to choose the type of multithreading you want.

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion If you want to write your own multithreading operating system from scratch or at least write your own scheduler, I believe [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html) will be very useful. Chapter 8 (Multiple-Processor Management) of Volume 3 (System Programming Guide) has a lot of information about how to implement multithreading.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use just

```
jmp segment:offset

call segment:offset
```

Answer (score 1):

Only far control transfer instructions (jmp, call, ret) can change the CS or EIP registers. I think the CS register can only be changed in real mode.

RET basically takes the value at ESP (stack pointer) and pushes that onto IP/EIP.  Then the ESP is incremented by 8 plus the immediate offset (if exists).

Answer (score 1):

To change both `cs` and `ip` registers, use the following in AT&T syntax:

```
ljmp $segment, $offset
```

Or the following in Intel syntax:

```
jmp segment:offset
```